# "Make up a sentence with the present perfect" or "make up a sentence in the present perfect"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which preposition I use in the following sentence: *in* or *with*? For example:

> Please make up a sentence **in** the present perfect to let it sink in.
>
> Please make up a sentence **with** the present perfect to let it sink in.

Comment: Why not “using the present perfect”?

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to say "please make up positive sentence in/with the present perfect"?

Comment: "a present perfect sentence" is an option